# problem with removing UILabel from View 

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I have a UILabel in my view. I want to remove the UILabel if a certain function is being called. I have tried a couple of ways, but its not working!

Codes tried:

```
[[self.view viewWithTag:1] setHidden:YES];
```

or

```
label.hidden=YES;
```

or

```
[label removeFromSuperview];
```

I have tried all of these codes, but to no avail. Cany anyone kindly let me know what I am missing here ? Thanks.

Other part of my code:

```
UILabel *startLabel=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(55, 45, 300, 30)] autorelease];    
UILabel *startLabel2=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 65, 300, 30)] autorelease];

if ((internetActive==NO)||(hostActive==NO)) {

    status=1;
    //add the label

    startLabel.text=@"Cannot connect to server.";
    startLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    startLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    startLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    startLabel.tag=1;

    [self.view addSubview:startLabel];



    startLabel2.text=@"Please check your connection.";
    startLabel2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    startLabel2.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    startLabel2.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    startLabel2.tag=2;

    [self.view addSubview:startLabel2];

    startLabel.hidden=NO;
    startLabel2.hidden=NO;

}

else if ((internetActive==YES) &&(hostActive==YES))
{
    if(status==1)
    {

        //[startLabel removeFromSuperview];
        //[startLabel2 removeFromSuperview];

        //[[self.view viewWithTag:1] setHidden:YES];
        //[[self.view viewWithTag:2] setHidden:YES];

        NSLog(@"INSIDE!");

        startLabel.hidden=YES;
        startLabel2.hidden=YES;

        [startLabel removeFromSuperview];
        [startLabel2 removeFromSuperview];

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the function you refer to is called, and are you sure a label with tag `1` is in your view?

Comment: ...and are you sure your label has tag 1?

Comment: @WTP and @Saphrosit : Yes, I am sure the function is being called...and I have a label with tag 1 (I have updated my question with my code for the UILabels).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is all that code in a single method? If yes.. you're creating new `startLabel` and `startLabel2` and try to remove them in the `else` part of the code, but those are not the labels that you added as subviews. Make the labels as member of the class, and only alloc them once in the `init/viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: thanks, it worked nicely...donno how I missed this..my bad :(

Answer (score 6):

All the methods you listed works. So I'm afraid that you are not searching your bug at the right place.

Make sure that :

1. the `label` instance you are getting is the good one
2. there is only one `label` instance (you could just removing a duplicate that you accidentally inserted...)

One **very** efficient way to debug these kind of issues is (I do this many times a day...) :

1. put a breakpoint where you are removing the label
2. when breakpoint hit, enter that command in `gdb` console :

   ```
   > po [[self view] recursiveDescription]
   ```

   > `recursiveDescription` will display a tree of `[self view]` subviews, with ***adresses*** and many useful informations like coordinates... hidden... That will allow you to clearly understand what is going on in that view.
3. go to next step, after you `removeFromSuperview` call, play again the command, and look what changed... or not. Check objects adresses carefully.

Learn gdb and debugging in general, and you will never have to ask these kind of questions again :)

Comment: imho it is better to know *how to find the solution* than just having "the solution"... ;)